# is there a possible way to extract the DAG of spark job without execution?

Tags: apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs

Is there a possible way to extract a DAG with all its components ( stages and tasks ) without executing or running a job?

I have an idea: before an action occurs, I extract the dependencies of RDDs related to that action and from that, I may create DAG.

Comment: hey, can we do that?

Comment: Hello, I couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `rdd.toDebugString` is what you are looking for.